# c# random numbers always same

Tags: random, numbers, repeat

Hy I want to create simple 3x3 matrice that contains only 0 and 1 elements. However, when I create 2D array 5x5 of my matrice object `Racunalo` that contains that 3x3 matrice, all 25 matrices have 0 and 1 elements on exact same positions, but I want that all matrices are different. How to make that? If there is some good soul who knows soultion, I would appreciate your help. Here is my code:

```
public class Racunalo
{
    public int[,] informacija = new int[3, 3];
    public void popuniInformacijuRacunala()
    {
        Random rand = new Random(Guid.NewGuid().GetHashCode());
        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++)
            {
                informacija[i, j] = rand.Next(0,2);
            }
        }
    }
}

public class Resetka
{
    public static Racunalo[,] resetkaRacunala = new Racunalo[5, 5];

    public void popuniInformacijeSvihRacunala()
    {
        Racunalo rac = new Racunalo();
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < 5; j++)
            {
                rac.popuniInformacijuRacunala();
                resetkaRacunala[i, j]=rac;
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that all Randoms are created with the same seed.
every Racunalo have the same guid as it is an object identifier.
try creating a new random with no parameters

Random rand = new Random();

or seeding every random with a different value (maybe use system clock time)

Comment: I tried all possible solutions, including your `Random rand = new Random();` and I always get same results. Also with system clock it's same problem.

Comment: Try making that Random object static and creating it only once
so that all instances of Racunalo will use the same random